# Display a div below an input field of the exact width using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I currently use the following code to position a div directly below an input text field on focus. The problem is the width of the div varies between browsers. Is there a way to ensure the div that appears is the exact width as my input field?

```
  // get the field position
  var inputField = $('#inputfield');
  var fieldDiv = $('div.divname');
  var sf_pos    = field.offset();
  var sf_top    = sf_pos.top;
  var sf_left   = sf_pos.left;
  // get the input field size
  var sf_height = inputField.height();
  var sf_width  = inputField.width();

  fieldDiv.css("position","absolute");
  fieldDiv.css("left", sf_left);
  fieldDiv.css("top", sf_top + sf_height + 6);
  fieldDiv.css("width", sf_width);

  $('#inputfield').focus(function() {
    fieldDiv.fadeIn('medium');
  }).blur(function() {
    fieldDiv.fadeOut('medium');
  });
```

Comment: Perhaps the css reset by Eric Meyer helps you: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ - With this you should be able to achieve the same width in nearly every browser

Comment: thanks! i use yui3 reset and base styles. i prefer that to Eric Meyer's as YUI doesn't reset all html formatting but rather normalises it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this may be related to IE not respecting the box model, and some browsers will also include borders in the widths and others wont.

have you tried using outterWidth() instead of width()?

also
You can hack it and add offsets that are browser dependent, for example:

```
width += ($.support.boxModel ? 0 : 2);
```

Comment: you're a genius! I changed width() to outerWidth() and minus 2 pixels and it became the same width :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an inevitable part of using CSS. Sure, you can hack away at your CSS until the early morning hours so that everything renders the same in all browsers with the same CSS, but we all have deadlines. I've found the simplest solution for tweaking element dimensions between browsers is [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). You can also define separate style sheet files for different browsers (that contain only the differences) and load those accordingly.

Comment: thanks :) i use conditional IE comments for those nasty display quirks.